# jq - sorting value by a related value

Tags: json, sorting, jq

Basically I'm just trying to make a list of NCAA March Madness teams sorted by their respective seeds.

I'm using the JSON file from http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2017/03/17/scoreboard.html. It's actually JSONP, but I convert it to JSON before parsing through it using:

```
jq -s -R  '.[1+index("("): rindex(")")] | fromjson'
```

Piping that into the following command I can generate a nice list of the teams:

```
jq -r '.scoreboard[].games[] | select(.bracketRound=="First Round" and .bracketRegion=="EAST") | .home,.away | .nameRaw'
```

...but I want them to be in order of their seed. I've tried using sort and sort_by in various ways to no avail. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data, the following filter:

```
[ .scoreboard[].games[]
  | select(.bracketRound=="First Round" and .bracketRegion=="EAST")
  | (.home, .away) ]
| sort_by(.teamSeed | tonumber) 
| .[]
| [.teamSeed, .nameRaw ]
```

produces:

```
["2","Duke"]
["3","Baylor"]
["6","SMU"]
["7","South Carolina"]
["10","Marquette"]
["11","USC"]
["14","New Mexico St."]
["15","Troy"]
```

If you just want the "nameRaw" values, then replace the last line of the filter by: `| .nameRaw`

Note that `tonumber` is required here as the seed values are given as strings.

#### Handling multiple top-level objects

In a comment, the OP gave a pastebin (https://pastebin.com/1eTAX4y3) consisting of two top-level objects each with a "scoreboard".  Let us therefore consider the case of an arbitrary number of such objects.

For clarity, we begin by defining a function for selecting the home/away objects from a JSON object with "scoreboard":

```
def games:
  [.scoreboard[].games[]
   | select(.bracketRound=="First Round" and .bracketRegion=="EAST")
   | (.home, .away) ] ;
```

Using the -s command-line option, we can ensure the JSON input is an array of objects.  The arrays produced by `games` can be combined using `add`:

```
map(games)
| add
| sort_by(.teamSeed | tonumber) 
| .[]
| [.teamSeed, .nameRaw ]
```

Given the pastebin data, the invocation using the command-line options -s and -c options produces:

```
["1","Villanova"]
["2","Duke"]
["3","Baylor"]
["4","Florida"]
["5","Virginia"]
["6","SMU"]
["7","South Carolina"]
["8","Wisconsin"]
["9","Virginia Tech"]
["10","Marquette"]
["11","USC"]
["12","UNCW"]
["13","East Tenn. St."]
["14","New Mexico St."]
["15","Troy"]
["16","Mt. St. Mary's"]
```

Comment: I almost had it too. Just needed 'tonumber'. However, I am running into an issue brought on by a piece that I neglected to mention. I am merging two JSON files together because the first round is played over two days (ergo two separate files). I use jq -s .[] *.json to do this. But when using your filter, it separates them instead of sorting them together. Here's the generated JSON file to reference: https://pastebin.com/1eTAX4y3

Comment: Now that I'm looking at that "merged" JSON file, it's not really even merged at all... I can see why it's having an issue sorting them together. They are two separate arrays. Is there a way to merge these properly?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
jq -r '
def NameAndSeed(f): f | {nameRaw, "teamSeed" : (.teamSeed | tonumber)};
[ 
  .scoreboard[].games[]
  | select(.bracketRound=="First Round" and .bracketRegion=="EAST")
  | NameAndSeed(.home), NameAndSeed(.away)
]
| sort_by(.teamSeed) 
| .[].nameRaw'
```

To get sort_by to do what I think you want, I put the objects in an array and converted the teamSeed values to numbers.